# Suppress embedded Jetty server version

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

Would it be possible to hide the following output produced by Jetty?

```
2012-04-08 10:52:35.467:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2012-04-08 10:52:35.623:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4725
```

I have tried configuring the server with the xml, but turns out this output is not redirected with the following gist: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/StdErrStdOut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Jetty 8, the documentation is located at 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/

Jetty writes this info during startup of the Server

```
LOG.info("jetty-"+__version);
```

If you use the StdErr Logger, i.e. there is no SLF4J Logging Framework on your classpath,
you can use the system property

*org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL*

to configure the the log level.
*org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL* supports the LogLevels ALL|DEBUG|INFO|WARN.

For further information about Jetty 7,8.x  and how to use external logging frameworks with jetty have a look at [Jetty Logging](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Logging)

Comment: Thanks, I suppose setting it to the level to `WARN` might suppress the version.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `StdErrLog` level to `WARN`, before starting your server:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL", "WARN");
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog.setProperties(p);
```